# Syntax coloring/highlighting not working anymore

Tags: javascript, eclipse, wildwebdeveloper

After updating the Wild-Web-Developer plugin  to the recent version (0.10.1.202007101231) within Eclipse 2020-06 the syntax coloring/highlighting for *.js files is not working anymore.

Does anyone experience a similar problem and how can it be solved?

Comment: Just found it out myself. You just have to (re)configure the "Generic Text Editor" as default under General > Editors > File Associations for the *.js files.

Comment: Was there a different default?

Comment: Yes, in my case the 'Text Editor' was the default.